# Hadoop CopyToLocal creates .crc files

Tags: hadoop, copy

Hadoop `copyToLocal` is creating `.crc` files in the destination directory along with the actual data files which is unnecessary for me and fiddle with my further data processing. Is there a way to avoid that from being created instead of deleting it later?

```
  val config = new Configuration()
  val fs = FileSystem.get(config)
  fs.copyToLocalFile(new Path(src),new Path(dest))
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's a checksum file. Why is it annoying? It's there for validation

Comment: Edited the question. Annoy is not the right word.

Answer (score 5):

Before you copy the file, use one or both of these

```
fs.setWriteChecksum(false)
fs.setVerifyChecksum(false)
```

However, as I mentioned, it's a file checksum, which means it's necessary for validation of a successful copy. if you had a file of the same name with different content, then it's actually a different file, and you should probably handle that case.

Answer (score 5):

There is another version of copyToLocal function in java.

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(boolean delSrc, Path src, Path dst, boolean useRawLocalFileSystem);
```

Where RawLocalFileSystem is non crc file system.So,It will not create any crc files at local

```
**delSrc** whether to delete the src
**src** path
**dst** path
**useRawLocalFileSystem** whether to use RawLocalFileSystem as local file system or not.
```

So making useRawLocalFileSystem=true will solve your problem.